# Notebook (.nb) → Jupyter (.ipynb) converter besides Mathematica?

Tags: math, file-converter

Is there a way to convert Mathematica Notebook files (.nb) to Jupyter files (.ipynb) without using Mathematica?
Is there a free online utility or other piece of software that can do this?